# Selenium finds but won't click button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate submission of LinkedIn's advanced search form (https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?adv=true&trk=federated_advs). It only loads properly once you're logged into your account.

Here's the HTML for the search button:

```
<div class="form-controls">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" class="submit-advs">
```

I cannot seem to figure out why the following does not click the "submit" button:

```
find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="submit-advs"]').click()
```

I can't see how I'm doing anything wrong. This works perfectly fine for clicking everything else on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit is done by: `find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="submit-advs"]').submit()`.

If you submit the form, it should work with only one command. In this case your XPath would have to be: `find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="submit-advs"]/parent::form').submit()`.

Comment: Thank you. Oddly enough I tried this and it didn't seem to work by itself, but if I do `element.click()` followed by `element.submit()` it does work.

Comment: Thank you but that actually doesn't seem to work. I know it could be cleaner but I'm OK with doing both .click and .submit for now. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_element_by_class('submit-advs').click()
```

Would be cleaner

Comment: You're right. It's cleaner, if not faster. I've just gotten accustomed to using Xpath because of the vagaries of parsing these pages.